# Center a multirow row table

Tags: tables, multirow

The content of the latex table does not align to the center of the multirow cell.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}

\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[hbt!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
er & \thead{erg\\eg\\ \text{[ff]}}  & \thead{egeg \\ \text{[fff]}}  & $ff_ef [-]$ &  \thead{wf\\wf} & \thead{wfwff\\wfw} \\ \hline
evev & 433 & 345 & 0.334 & evevev & evev \\ \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{\thead{multivitamin\\tea}} & egeg & \multirow{3}{*}{411} & eg & ege egeg & grteg \\ \cline{2-2}\cline{4-6}
 & ege & & eg & \thead{eg eg\\eg} & \thead{eg eg\\ege\\eg} \\ \cline{2-2}\cline{4-6}
 & egg & & egeg & eg eg  & egeg \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{title}\label{tab1}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The `multivitamin tea` and `411` does not align to the center of the cell.

[image]

Comment: Use `\multirow{5}` instead of `\multirow{3}`.

Comment: Text that takes up more than one line currently is smaller than text that takes up multiplw lines. Is this intentional? If not, wither replace `\thead` with `\makecell` or add `\renemwcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize}` to your document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not centred because  the number-of-rows argument supposes one-lined cells in the rows. If you count the real number of lines in the three rows, you should use use \multirow{5}. Also note that, for fine-tuning, the number-of-rows can have a decimal part.

I simplified the code using `\multirowcell{…}` since you load `makecell`, and (unrelated), when in geometry, all margins have the same value, you can simply use as a parameter `[margin = …]`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}

\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[hbt!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
er & \thead{erg\\eg\\ \text{[ff]}} & \thead{egeg \\ \text{[fff]}} & $ff_ef [-]$ & \thead{wf\\wf} & \thead{wfwff\\wfw} \\ \hline
evev & 433 & 345 & 0.334 & evevev & evev \\ \hline
\multirowcell{5}{multivitamin\\tea} & egeg & \multirow{3}{*}{411} & eg & ege egeg & grteg \\ \cline{2-2}\cline{4-6}
 & ege & & eg & \thead{eg eg\\eg} & \thead{eg eg\\ege\\eg} \\ \cline{2-2}\cline{4-6}
 & egg & & egeg & eg eg & egeg \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{title}\label{tab1}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here are three versions of your table. In the first version, I only corrected the wrong first argument of `\multirow` and kept the inconsistent font sizes. In the second table, I also changed the font sized to make sure, the smaller font is only used in the column headers. In the last table, I used `nicematrix` and its `\Block` command instead of `\multirow` and made sure, the font size is consistent throughout the whole table.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}

\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{makecell}

\usepackage{nicematrix} % only needed for the last example.

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[hbt!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
er & \thead{erg\\eg\\ {[ff]}}  & \thead{egeg \\ {[fff]}}  & $ff_ef [-]$ &  \thead{wf\\wf} & \thead{wfwff\\wfw} \\ \hline
evev & 433 & 345 & 0.334 & evevev & evev \\ \hline
\multirow{5}{*}{\thead{multivitamin\\tea}} & egeg & \multirow{5}{*}{411} & eg & ege egeg & grteg \\ \cline{2-2}\cline{4-6}
 & ege & & eg & \thead{eg eg\\eg} & \thead{eg eg\\ege\\eg} \\ \cline{2-2}\cline{4-6}
 & egg & & egeg & eg eg  & egeg \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{corrected multirow option to vertically center contents}\label{tab1}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[hbt!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\thead{er} & \thead{erg\\eg\\ {[ff]}}  & \thead{egeg \\ {[fff]}}  & \thead{$ff_ef [-]$} &  \thead{wf\\wf} & \thead{wfwff\\wfw} \\ \hline
evev & 433 & 345 & 0.334 & evevev & evev \\ \hline
\multirow{5}{*}{\makecell{multivitamin\\tea}} & egeg & \multirow{5}{*}{411} & eg & ege egeg & grteg \\ \cline{2-2}\cline{4-6}
 & ege & & eg & \makecell{eg eg\\eg} & \makecell{eg eg\\ege\\eg} \\ \cline{2-2}\cline{4-6}
 & egg & & egeg & eg eg  & egeg \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{corrected multirow option to vertically center contents + smaller font size in column headers only}\label{tab1}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[hbt!]
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{cccccc}[hvlines]
er & \makecell{erg\\eg\\ {[ff]}}  & \makecell{egeg \\ {[fff]}}  & $ff_ef [-]$ &  \makecell{wf\\wf} & \makecell{wfwff\\wfw} \\ 
evev & 433 & 345 & 0.334 & evevev & evev \\ 
\Block{3-1}{multivitamin\\tea} & egeg & \Block{3-1}{411} & eg & ege egeg & grteg \\
 & ege & & eg & \makecell{eg eg\\eg} & \makecell{eg eg\\ege\\eg} \\
 & egg & & egeg & eg eg  & egeg \\ \hline
\end{NiceTabular}
\caption{vertically centered content using nicematrix and its Block command + consistent font size throughout the table}\label{tab1}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```